# Do I need any German work or residence permits for a German company to hire me to work in France?

Tags: taxes, germany, france, resident-permit, india

I am a citizen and resident of India. I work as an independent software consultant. One of my customers is a company based in Germany. This German company has a client in Paris, France. The German company wants me to work at their client's Paris office for 1 year. It is a fixed term contract, and will end after 1 year.

It is clear that independent consultants cannot obtain work permits in France, unless they are setting up their own business in France with considerable investment. So I would be offered employment by the German company. The Germany company doesn't have any office or subsidiary in France.

I know for sure that I will need a French work permit. But will I also need German work and residence permits? Or will it be enough if I get the French work permit, and the German company hires me?

Also, which countries will tax my salary? I will receive my salary from the German company directly into my bank accounts in India. Will I have to pay any tax in France?

Comment: Does the German company have an office/subsidiary in France ?

Comment: No the Germany company does not have any office or subsidiary outside of Germany.

Comment: I see no reason you should need a German work permit but I guess you will have to pay taxes in France (you will effectively be living there and the work will be executed there, two reasons to make this income taxable under French law), although that could depend on tax treaties. The rules regarding health insurance might also be complicated (it's mandatory in Germany but perhaps your employer has a way to exempt you from the mandatory contributions as you won't be living there…) Unfortunately, I have no official source to offer and I might be wrong (hence a comment and not an answer).